# Which model should I use? (genomic problem)

Tags: generalized-linear-model, zero-inflation, link-function

I have problems with choosing which model / link function should I use for my analysis.

My response: numbers from -100% to +500% (increase of tumor after therapy, may switch to ratios or log-ratios, so -50% will become 1/2 or -1)

My predictors: numbers N from 0% to 100% which denote "mutation of gene X happened in N% of tumor". The problem is - major part of patients do not have mutations in any particular gene, so for most samples it will be 0%. Data matrix look like: a looot of 0s (more than 95%) and sometimes a number from 0% to 100%. So none of "classic" models (I denote "classic model" as "model that I know") can be applied due to violated assumptions and really not clear distribution of residuals. So it is like "zero inflation in predictors".

I have tried random forest...negative R^2 XD

I have approx 100 genes to investigate and approx 100 samples, if it matters. Could you give any direction on where to look?

Comment: Random forest may require a sample size of perhaps 200 * 100 = 20000 to be reliable in your situation as described [here](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-14-137).  Strange distributions of predictor values are not of major concern.  If you were doing regression this particular situation can be handled by having for each predictor x an indicator variable for x > 0 and also putting x and x$^2$ in the model.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I clearly understand why we need indicator variable, thanks a lot, but why do we need to put x^2?

Comment: Inlcude $x^2$ if you do not know that the effect of the predictor is linear when it is greater than zero.  Better would be cubic spline functions but quadratic effects may be adequate approximators here.

Comment: thank you a lot, your help is invaluable!

Comment: @FrankHarrell I have one obvious problem with this solution - too many predictors when I add x^2 or dummy variables. I've proceeded with analysis without additional predictors (0% in some gene means that 0% of cancer cells have this mutation and it seems legit to use 0 as continuous variable). Does the dummy variables really necessary? QQplot looks not that bad, and the most important thing - almost all significant finding were already described in literature. I have your book, so if it is too long to describe - could you please refer to the chapter in your book where I can read about this?

Comment: Hard to say from information given.   Only suggestion is to use penalized regression and compare effective AIC of 3 models: fully linear, indicator variable + linear, indicator + linear + square.

Comment: Thanks again a lot! I also plan to cross validate the models and look at something in the end, still not sure at what, since number of predictor will vary.

Comment: Just make sure that the cross-validation repeats afresh all supervised learning steps for each inner loop.